# problem with ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I did this:
[How do I install drivers for Realtek RTL8812BU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu/1079500)"

1. I'm having problems associating.

`iwconfig` shows:

> wlx1cbfce9e4193  unassociated
>   Nickname:""
>   Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
>   Sensitivity:0/0
>   Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>   Power Management:off
>   Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
>   Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>   Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

```
sudo iwconfig wlx1cbfce9e4193 essid local50 key xxxxxxxxx
```

> Error for  wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
>       invalid argument "xxxxxxxxx".

2. How do I rename the device from wlx1cbfce9e4193 to wlan0?
3. Should I be able to make this card an 802.11AC access point? That is what I wanted for my Raspberry Pi4 running OpenWrt. :-) I'll settle for it working as a client and AP on my desktop.
4. What are the chances this driver would make it into the kernel (or at least a precompiled package)?

Comment: "key xxxxxxxxx" in iwconfig implies that your encryption is WEP. I doubt that is the case. Is Network Manager installed and running? If so, that's where you should direct the wireless to connect. Does your card and driver combination support AP mode? `iw list` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: '$ iw list
Wiphy phy0
        max # scan SSIDs: 9
        max scan IEs length: 2304 bytes
        max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
        max # match sets: 0
        max # scan plans: 1
        max scan plan interval: -1
        max scan plan iterations: 0
        Retry short limit: 7
        Retry long limit: 4
        Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
        Supported Ciphers:
                * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
                * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
                * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
                * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)

Comment: Keep scrolling down to the supported modes. Is ‘AP’ listed?

Comment: Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO

Comment: I want WPA. I think I need to set up wpa_supplicat so I am trying that.

Comment: An y idea what this means from wpa_supplicant? wlx1cbfce9e4193: Event ASSOC_REJECT (12) received
wlx1cbfce9e4193: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1

Comment: Is it a country code mismatch? I specified ca in wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: I tried adding the rtw_country_code module parameter. It didn't help. :-(

Comment: Is this a desktop installation using Network Manager? If so, that is the place to direct the wireless to connect. If not, then use netplan. ASSOC-REJECT means, generally, that the access point declined to associate. Perhaps the password or some other parameter is incorrect.

Comment: I turned off network manager because I read it conflicts. My AP is a Broadcom router running FreshTomato. My phone associates and says it is on channel 52. iw list says "5260 MHz [52] (24.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)" so I think the eeprom of the card is set to the World regdomain and the router doesn't let me pick the channel (just 'auto'). I think the router is choosing channel 52 because that is valid in Canada but the card says no. I tried to set up an AP and this was the clue "Channel 56 (primary) not allowed for AP mode, flags: 0x197b NO-IR RADAR".

Comment: I got it working as an AP (not channel 52, etc :-().iwconfig says "wlx1cbfce9e4193  IEEE 802.11an". I'm going to see if I can find a Windows machine, if it associates to channel 52 then I'll be annoyed.

Comment: I noticed the adapter I had was only recognized as USB 2 (I need USB 3 for AC). My 2nd adapter was the same. The 3rd adapter has an AU chipset.