# Can not install newest Ubuntu Version (18.04) from USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb-installation

I flashed my USB drive with Balena Etcher and tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 as dual boot on my desktop. 
On the laptop, this worked without issues. On the laptop, 
Im stuck at the loading screen and the right side of the screen is flickering (picture attached)
[Flickering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN8l7.jpg)

Could this be a graphic card issue? Why is it stuck? Do I have to wait for a longer time? 
Some system specs:

- CPU:  AMD Ryzen 7 2700X
- Mainboard: X470 Master SLI L3.24 (ASRock)
- Graphics Card: Nividia GeForce RTX 2060

So many questions, and no error message or anything that would help :(
I hope someone has an idea how to solve this.

Cheers.

UPDATE: I managed to get into the options menu at boot by pressing TAB, I will perform some tests. Apparentely there is 1 erroneous file on the boot drive. I will try another program to create the boot drive. Maybe RUFUS will work.

UPDATE2: Okay, same issue of RUFUS, but I pressed Escape / F1 in the loading screen and got some more information. Apparentely there is some issue starting the Journal Service. Screen attached: [Error Message Loading Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi019.jpg) . I will redownload version 19.10 to see if it fixes anything. Maybe there was an issue with the ISO.

UPDATE3: Alright, same issue on 19.10, but this time the disk check yield no errors. Still, the Journal Service can not start. Anyone has an idea why?

UPDATE (HOPEFULLY LAST): Apparentely, it was something with the graphics card like also hinted in an answer. When choosing the safe graphics mode, I can procceed to installation :-) I hope I will be able to set everything up now. I hope these hints help some other people as well. I did not really see the safe graphics option in 18.04, so another way is propably required there.

So I still had to follow the instructions here: [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)
to get inside Ubuntu and now my screen resolution is horrible. I am not happy at all with this whole process. Why is it so complicated to install this OS? Also, the startup takes ages and I don't know why. Additionally, I am connected to the INternet via a USB dongle which Ubuntu does not recognize. WHY?

I went back to 18.04 just to be sure and I still had to do really complicated stuff ([How do I install drivers for Realtek RTL8812BU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu)) just to get my wifi dongle working...

Comment: With nVidia you need nomodeset (replace quiet splash) on the Linux line in grub menu with UEFI boot of installer. See grub example, first part is old BIOS boot which you do not normally want with new systems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I also have a Nvidia but I didn't want to use Nvidia video drivers right of the bat in case there were some compatibility issues. I also see the flickering when I'm booting but that's momentary and then I get the boot menu. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: The issue with the bad screen resolution sounds like a driver issue. Did you install the proprietary nvidia drivers? You can do so by searching for "additional drivers" in the dash and activating the nvidia drivers.

Comment: I could not set screen resolution. So I ran sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall , removed the "nomodeset" because i could not set any resolution, restarted and now it appears to work with full resolution