# Debugging installation of RTL8812BU wifi dongel

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

#### Situation

I run Ubuntu 16.04 (4.15.0-48-generic) on my desktop and I would like to get my [Netgear AC1200 WiFi USB adapter, model A6150](http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Netgear_A6150) (with Realtek RTL8812BU chipset) to work.

I have followed the [solution by chili555 in this SE question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu), and all the steps terminated successfully. I.e. I have installed drivers from this repo:

```
https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.4_26334.20180126_COEX20171012-5044.git
```

And I have rebooted my system.

#### Problem

It doesn't seem to work, i.e. when I unplug the ethernet cable I loose my connection (with the dongel in). I don't know what to do now (and I am very new to linux).

#### More info

1. In the `All Settings`>`Network` I don't see anything wifi-related. Does my desktop need to be setup for to use wifi somehow?

[image]

2. Output of `lsusb` (among others) show that my dongle is found

`Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0846:9055 NetGear, Inc.`

3. Outout of `lshw -C network` (entire output)

   ```
   network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
   Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: enp5s0
   version: 06
   serial: bc:5f:f4:0d:49:48
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.137.249 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:17 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d2104000-d2104fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
   ```
4. `rfkill list all` doesn't output anything.
5. Output of [Wireless Info Script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205): https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2JbYpzdx7q/

#### Updates (e.g. based on comments)

1. `sudo modprobe 88x2bu` doesn't produce any output. I.e. it instantaneously asks for the next input, without outputting anything.
2. Output of `dmesg | grep -i rtl`

```
    [    3.054709] r8169 0000:05:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl at 0x        (ptrval), bc:5f:f4:0d:49:48, XID 0c900800 IRQ 30
    [ 5573.899004] RTW: rtl88x2bu v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
    [ 5573.899005] RTW: rtl88x2bu BT-Coex version = COEX20180427-5959
    [ 5573.899033] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl88x2bu
    [ 6025.932877] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtl88x2bu
    [ 6028.668674] RTW: rtl88x2bu v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959
    [ 6028.668675] RTW: rtl88x2bu BT-Coex version = COEX20180427-5959
    [ 6028.668705] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl88x2bu
```

3. Output of `dkms status`:

```
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.15.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.15.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.15.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.15.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.15.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
ndiswrapper, 1.60, 4.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.130, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.130, 4.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu, 5.2.4.4, 4.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl88x2bu, 5.3.1, 4.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: built
```

4. Output of `modinfo 88x2bu | grep 9055`: None
5. Output of `modprobe -c | grep 0846 | grep 9055`: None

Comment: With such an old kernel, you may need to get an older version of the driver: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.4.1_22719_COEX20170518-4444.20170613

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe 88x2bu` and then: `dmesg | grep -i rtl`

Comment: @chili555 I have updated the question with the output you requested.

Comment: I noticed in the output of the `dmsg` command states version `v5.3.1` and not `v5.2.4` as I expected. This is a left over from a previous attempt that I thought I had cleaned up - still: I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Please edit question to include results for `dkms status`

Comment: Let's also see: `modinfo 88x2bu | grep 9055` I suspect it's empty.

Comment: I have edited the question based on the recommendation from @Jeremy31 and chili555. It looks like you are onto something :)

Comment: Result for `modprobe -c | grep 0846 | grep 9055`

Comment: That one is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in terminal

```
sudo dkms uninstall rtl88x2bu/5.2.4.4
sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.2.4.4 --all
sudo dkms uninstall rtl88x2bu/5.3.1
sudo dkms remove rtl88x2bu/5.3.1 --all
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu</pre></code>
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Reboot

Comment: This worked just as I had hoped! Just so I understand what went wrong and what you did - is this correct: I had tried to install two different (old) drivers that were in conflict. If I had installed either of them correctly it would still have worked (?). But your fix was to uninstall everything and install the most recent version of the drivers?

Comment: PS I think there is a typo in line 7. I used `VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)` from the github repo instead

Comment: The older versions did not have your device listed at all but I found it in the newest version.  I put line 7 exactly as what you used but there must be something in the format that removed some things.  Changed the code tags a bit and it shows correctly now