# USB wifi adapter is not recognized in Linux ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have a USB wifi adapter and I don't seem to make it work. it working before (2 months ago) but now it's not. running `lsusb` returns the driver:

`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0 802.11ac 1200M Adapter`

I'm not sure if the adapter is broken or I need a new driver and I looked on the internet and couldn't find and suitable driver for it.

Any help is much appreciated. I have already tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu) but didn't work. I think it's for some old drivers

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/devices and cloud use  that can use *snap* packages only.  Please clarify which product you are using  (*year* only releases mean a different product since 2016)

Comment: There are multiple answers there; did you try all of them? What was the result of each?

Answer (score 0):

Possible the wireless driver is not working any more after some updates, you should try to re-compile & re-install the wireless driver

```
https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu

make

make install

# reboot & check connection
```