# Wifi adapter not found in Ubuntu 20.04 on HP touchsmart 600

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, hp, realtek-wireless

I searched a lot, but most of what I found is for broadcom or doesn't work.

the computer is a HP touchsmart 600 and I think it has a realtek wifi card, but I'm not sure.
The wifi adapter I want to use is a usb realtek wifi adapter.

The problem is that the wifi sometimes connects but most of the time it doesn't, and once it connects it almost immediately disconnects.

I already tried everything I found and could think of, help is appreciated.

edit:
output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21b1 Broadcom Corp. HP Bluetooth Module
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 04f3:01a4 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Wireless Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c518 Logitech, Inc. MX610 Laser Cordless Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0409:0059 NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b14c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd CNF8050 Webcam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1926:0006 NextWindow 1950 HID Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0158 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB 2.0 multicard reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output of `lshw -C network` (lash --class network didn't work):

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3092 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: ac:81:12:03:53:21
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.8.0-41-generic firmware=0.40 ip=192.168.1.44 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:fbdf0000-fbdfffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 03
       serial: 70:71:bc:aa:9f:33
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-41-generic firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fbfff000-fbffffff memory:f8ffc000-f8ffffff memory:fbfc0000-fbfdffff
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `sudo lsusb`? Specific information will make it possible for someone to offer a specific solution 

Comment: Show us ([Edit] your question)  `sudo lshw --class network`.

Comment: I added the output of both of the commands.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu

Comment: @Pilot6 thnaks a lot! that worked, but I had to follow the instructions in the github readme and not the answer.
but how do I disable the built in wifi? its connecting and disconnecting all the time and thats pretty annoying.