# USB wi-fi adapter drivers. HELP!

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, 20.04, usb

I have the archer-t4u wi-fi usb adapter, recently bought it after discovering it has total Linux support. Is it there anyway to make it work on the latest Ubuntu LTS release? The official website for TP-Link drivers only provides drivers to the old 16.04 LT release

http://tp-link.com/en/support/download/archer-t4u/

Looking and asking around on the internet i saw someone commenting about checking the drivers of the chip inside of the adapter. This is outside of my abilities however, i don't know how to follow this trail further.

http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T4U
If i am not mistaken and this website is correct, the chip is the Realtek RTL8812AU.

*Update*: Most certainly the chip inside my USB Wireless Adapter is the RTL8812AU.

However, trying to install the drivers via

```
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

and rebooting my system didn't work.

I sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: If it actually have the chip you mentioned then just get a temporary internet connection (Ethernet or USB tethering from your phone) and install `rtl8812au-dkms`. Reboot and you're done. It's fully supported so not a scam. Do you also call scam to any product sold as compatible with Windows but requires drivers?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Maybe scam isn't the right word. I am just somewhat pissed the product was being advertised and sold as having full support while, in reality, TP-Link only offered old drivers for old kernels. No one likes wasting money in vain. Anyways, i did what you said and it didn't work, i guess the website was wrong.

Comment: Please confirm the actual chipset with `lsusb`then edit the question with the relevant line so you can get the help you need. Meanwhile please avoid uneducated assumptions that help nobody. TP-Link as well as many other vendors often offer drivers when they're needed. An example is the chipset you mentioned for which it WAS necessary to install some proprietary drivers, compiling from Realtek's source code or installing via PPA but are no longer needed as soon as major distros either support it OOTB or via a package already in said distros' repositories.

Comment: In terminal, check `mokutil --sb-state` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled for the driver to load

Comment: @ChanganAuto lsusb only gives me "Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2357:0115 TP-Link". I did some searching using the device manager on a Windows OS notebook i have, and my research landed me on the same chipset on my post, the RTL8812AU. I don't know why i couldn't install the drivers via the terminal.

Comment: @Jeremy31 typing " check mokutil --sb-state " into the terminal failed, "Failed to read config, exiting".

Comment: The command is `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: 2357 : **0115** corresponds to TP-LINK Archer T4U **v3** that has **RTL8812BU** instead (all previous versions had ..AU indeed). So, several options mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu and yes, either way you must disable Secure Boot in UEFI, if applicable. @Jeremy31 can confirm whether or not the drivers mentioned in the linked question are still valid or if there are better now and eventually make your question a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @Jeremy31 "EFI variables are not supported on this system"

Comment: That has been archived there are instructions for dkms install at https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu

Comment: I followed the links posted and it worked! Thank you all very much!