# Realtek 8812BU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB NIC is not working in Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, realtek

I just installed Ubuntu 20.4 on my Dell OptiPlex 3040 desktop PC.

Now I am having an extremely hard time finding the drivers for "Realtek 8812BU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB NIC." so I can connect to the Internet using my Wireless LAN adapter. I checked the Realtek website and saw that they do have the drivers only for Windows and they do not offer drivers for Linux.

I also checked the Ubuntu community page and found some workaround to fix this issue, but all to no avail. I also checked some other websites and they have the same terminal script that someone could find on the AskUbunty community page.

Can someone please point me in the right direction like where and how I can download the drivers for Realtek 8812BU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB NIC for Ubuntu 20.4?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install drivers for Realtek RTL8812BU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079377/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-realtek-rtl8812bu)

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.4 What is the real version?